# How to restrict Google api client access to specific groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

I'm currently working with Google Directory to store my groups, and I'm using the Google Api client to fetch information about these groups. Right now, I'm able to retrieve all the groups using the api client, but I'm wondering if there's a way to limit the results to only specific groups.

Is there a way to achieve this through the registered app configuration or any other method  ?

appreciate any guidance or examples on how to restrict the groups that I get from the api client.

Comment: i'm using google python api client

Comment: are you using a service account?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo yep